# Norm-bounded input

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

What is norm-bounded input?

The expression is used in section 4.4 of 'Building High-level Features Using Large Scale Unsupervised Learning' by Le et al. I can find papers using the term, but not any information on how it is defined. The sentence in the paper is: "In particular, we find the normbounded input x which maximizes the output f of the tested neuron."

What is norm-bounded input? And why would that be used when optimizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Andrew Ng's lecture nodes at web.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder.pdf it is explained that the norm-bounded input is used to get a non-trivial answer. That makes sense as otherwise all the input with positive weights would simply go to the maximum value and reverse for neurons with negative weights. See snippet from the notes below:

[image]